# Platform declaration clash kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin, viewmodel

I am seeing the following error

> Platform declaration clash: The following declarations have the same
> JVM signature (getHosts()Landroidx/lifecycle/MutableLiveData;):
> private final fun `<get-hosts>`(): MutableLiveData<List> defined
> in com.example.xx.viewmodel.HostsViewModel public final fun
> getHosts(): MutableLiveData<List> defined in
> com.example.xx.viewmodel.HostsViewModel

What am I doing wrong?

```
class HostsViewModel : ViewModel() {
    private val hostsService = HostsService()
    
    private val hosts: MutableLiveData<List<Host>> by lazy {
        MutableLiveData<List<Host>>().also {
            loadHosts()
        }
    }
    fun getHosts(): MutableLiveData<List<Host>> {
        return hosts
    }
    private fun loadHosts(){
        hosts.value = hostsService.getHosts().body()
    }

}
```

Comment: *What am I doing wrong?* You forgot about kotlin's autoproperties? `getHosts()` and `val hosts` seems to be the same for kotlin besides that one is private and one is public

Comment: @Selvin seems the exact thing given in the first code example of this url except users is swapped for hosts. no?https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/viewmodel

Comment: *seems the exact thing...no?* no, it is not ... `MutableLiveData<List<X>> getX()` vs `LiveData<List<X>> getX()`

Comment: Didn't notice that. thanks

Comment: You don't wana expose `MutableLiveData` from `ViewModel` as then youll be able to change it value outside the ViewModel itself

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For every class property (`val`), Kotlin generates a getter called `getHosts()` and for `var` also a setter called `setHosts(MutableLiveData<List<Host>>  value)` as per Java's convention. It hides it from the Kotlin user as getters and setters are usually just boilerplate code without offering much value. As such, your own `getHosts()` method clashes with the generated method at compilation. You have multiple possibilities to solve this issue:

1. Rename `private val hosts` to something else, e.g. `private val internalHosts`
2. Annotate the `getHosts` method with `@JvmName("getHosts2")`. If you do that though, consider the possibility that someone might call your code from Java and in that case, the caller would need to call `getHosts2()` in Java code, which might not be such nice API-design.
3. Reconsider your api design. In your case, you could simply make `val hosts` public and remove your `getHosts()` entirely, as the compiler will auto-generate `getHosts()` for you.

In addition to that, you might want to consider not exposing `MutableLiveData` in general as mentioned in the comments.

**Edit**:

Also, I would recommend that you do this:

```
val hosts: MutableLiveData<List<Host>> by lazy {
    MutableLiveData<List<Host>>().also {
        it.value = hostsService.getHosts().body()
    }
}
```

and remove `loadHosts` to make your code more concise.